# DataGridView is not using my TypeConverters even though PropertyGrid does

Tags: .net, winforms

Using a subclass of `StringConverter`s (base class `TypeConverter`s) for comboboxes works great with propertygrid,
but does not work with datagridview.

I have a collection of a class, and that class has properties, and some of them are ornamented with `TypeConverter` attributes to make combo boxes. Here's an example.

```vb
<XmlAttribute(), Category("General")> _
<LookupTable(GetType(SiteStatus))> _
<TypeConverter(GetType(LookupTableConverter))> _
Public Property DispenserStatus As String = "A"
```

Like I say, it works splendidly with the `PropertyGrid` but when I bind the collection to a `DataGridView` I just see the raw value ("A" in this case) and no combo appears. No conversion is going on.

It's disappointing that Microsoft controls are not consistent. I already have instrumented my class library for combo boxes; I do not want to have to create a seperate framework just to make the `DataGridView` combos work. Scantly anything about it on Google; hence the post.

How can I make the `DataGridView` see my `TypeConverter`?
It should work, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is, the DataGridView simply doesn't support this feature, which is shocking, but true.

I wrote my own data grid (I know, right?), and it is working great!

Comment: Now that could be something you could elaborate a tiny bit more on.